# Xamarin studio doesn't start on mac osx 10.11.5 beta

Tags: macos, xamarin

I installed Xamarin Studio on my mac. After installation complete (everything seems correct) Xamarin studio does not start :S

When I click xamarin application and nothing happens.

My operating system version is El Capitan 10.11.5 Beta

What is could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you install xcode?

Here video showing installation Xamarin Studio on Mac:

https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/?v=Installing_Xamarin_on_OS_X

Comment: I installed xcode but nothing change still not working.